# Why aren't gamma rays more ionizing than beta and alpha rays considering the fact that it is the highest energy photon and very penetrative?

Tags: radiation, radioactivity, gamma-rays

Gamma rays are photons and light waves that have more than enough energy to excite an electron and break its bond. So why aren't they more ionizing than beta and alpha particles? Is this comparison valid for all kinds of EM waves/photons?

Can we say that gamma rays are the most ionizing of all EM spectrum, however it is not more ionising than either beta nor alpha waves?

I mean why doesn't being more penetrative than alpha and beta make it more ionising?

Comment: Well, (1) they are more penetrating meaning they don't interact as strongly, and (2) they are not charged so they don't interact as easily as an ion or electron (which of course takes you back to point 1).

Comment: @JonCuster so, even being the highest energy photon in the EM spectrum is no match for beta and alpha particles in terms of ionisation?

Comment: Typical process for generating ionized particle by a gamma is that it scatters off an electron (giving some fraction of its energy to the electron), and then the energetic electron produces the ionization. So, you have the built-in inefficiency of the scattering process compared with starting with an electron with the same energy as the gamma.

Comment: @JonCuster Beta particles are not as energetic as Gamma particles though.

Comment: Kind of depends on the gamma and the beta, no? Plus the gamma may go right through with no interaction, but the beta will interact strongly with matter.